# why is actor critic off policy

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I'm new to reinforcement learning and got stuck in actor critic.
What I've understood about actor critic method is that the actor outputs an action, which changes the state, and the critic receives the changed state from the environment. With the received state, the critic updates the policy. If this is true, isn't the policy being affected by the action and therefore policy is dependent on the actor's actions? Isn't this what on policy learning means?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, two versions are possible. You describe the online version, but offline one is also an option. Notice that this algorithm doesn't require running the training logic with each transition observed. This would be the 'online' case, where you choose an action with current policy, get new state and reward from the environment, and use this transition to calculate updates for your critic and actor. But you can train your model on transitions generated by other policies as well. For example you can add some noise to your actor network's output. You can as well save the generated transitions to a replay buffer and call the training method once a while with a randomly selected batch of them. Or, although it's not an usual approach, you could generate the transitions by using agent with totally different model (as long as the action's shape stays the same or you can translate that model's action to your action format). This would the the offline case, where you don't directly use transitions generated by the current policy.

Comment: Oh so as long as you don't directly use the transitions from the policy the system is offline? Thanks a lot.